# How do I quickly change the current calendar being used for new events in Lion?

Tags: macos, ical

I have different calendars for various types of things that I use to schedule my days.  This involves switching between the different calendars for different kinds of events when doing the scheduling.  In Snow Leopard, I could just select the calendar I wanted by clicking on it on the left.  With Lion, it looked like I might be able to get the same functionality with the little "Calendar" button in the upper left, but that just seems to allow me to rename the Calendars, without actually setting one as being currently active for creating new events.

I can edit each event individually, but that is rather tedious.  (Though Going into advanced preferences, and clicking the "Open events in a separate window" reduces the pain somewhat)

I can also set the default calendar in preferences, but that is even more tedious than editing the events.

So, how do I quickly change the current calendar being used for new events in Lion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the default calendar to "last selected calendar" then clicking a calendar via the "Calendar" button pop-over will actually set the currently active calendar for new events.